# What is the sql code for querying "belonging"?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

so the question is I have this Database

```
Driver (DriverNumber(pk), DriverName, CityNb(fk), Salary, DailyWorkingHours)

Bus (BusNumber(pk), Make, Capacity, CityNb(Fk)

Route (DepartureDate(pk),  BusNumber(pk) ,DriverNumber(fk),  DepartureCityNb(fk),  ArrivalCityNb(fk)

City (CityNb(pk), CityName)
```

I have this question

Show the name of all drivers who belong to same city that “John Smith” belongs to

and my answer is like that

```
Select Driver.DriverName
  from Driver
  INNER JOIN CITY ON
  Driver.CityNb=City.CityNb
```

but how to wirte to same city that...belong

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery to find the city of "John Smith". For example:

```
select driver_name
from driver
where city_nb in (
  select city_bn from driver where driver_name = 'John Smith'
)
```